# creating multiple DE's?

Tags: marketing-cloud

In my case we have to create nearly 10 DE's with same attributes in it.

So in normal process i have to create one by one copying it from master DE.

Is there any other way to create them at once?

Comment: you could use SOAP API, but honestly unless this is a repetitive task, it would take more time to develop the call, then it would to manually create the DEs through 'create from existing' or 'duplicate'.

Comment: Do you have the code?

Comment: This would be a good place to start: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_data_extension_using_web_service_api.htm

Comment: Thanks Gorton! can this SOAP code be used in exacttarget?

Comment: Yes - this is an example straight from its own help docs.

Answer (score 1):

[Create from existing data extension](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_de_from_de.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) would be your best bet.